# Geckofx V45 Post Request

Tags: geckofx

Is there any other method to send a post request without using the Navigate function. In some instances I need to able to send a post request to update some data but I don't want the browser to navigate to the php page.

Answer (score 0):

I used HttpWebRequest to Post data, to Login to a site and copy the cookies into a cookiecontainer

Then before going into a Authorized page via GeckoFX I copied over the cookies from the cookiecontainer over to GeckoFX.

```
 For Each cook As Net.Cookie In CookieContainer.GetCookies(New Uri(url))
        Gecko.CookieManager.Add("www.example.com", "/", cook.Name, cook.Value, False, True, False, DateTimeToUnixTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)))
    Next
```